How to Make Modal Code Run All the Time?
I'm very much a noob at this, both coding and blender, so sorry in advance. People have mentioned it before, sorry again, I followed a bunch of guides and I'm just trying to get stuff to work.
Anyway, I've been trying to get it to where I can control actions in blender with my voice. I've actually gotten it working after a lot of tries! When I speak, the cube moves, and when I'm not, it goes back to it's original position. You could make it do other things, whatever you put in the code really. However, it only really works when the mouse is moving. I've included a video of this in action:
https://youtu.be/kvKcSYVTgCc
What I want is for the mic to be recording and the cube being able to move all the time, not just when I move the mouse. I know that this is because I tied it event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE', but I really couldn't figure out how to get the code to work without that line.
I've seen the timer template, and a lot of other questions use timer as well, but that's also not what I want I think.
Is there a way to always have the modal code running, without having to do an event?
When I don't give it an event, it doesn't run at all. Is there some benign event that's always running in the background, without me needing to push buttons or do anything for it to happen?
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,  #32 bit floating point
channels=1, #mono audio
rate=44100, #44100 Hz, standard
input=True, #capture microphone audio
frames_per_buffer=1024) #chunk size of audio data at a time
   

class SpeakingPuppet(bpy.types.Operator):

bl_idname = "object.speaking_puppet"
bl_label = "Speaking Puppet"


def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
        data = stream.read(1024)
        audio = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32)
        spectrum = np.fft.fft(audio)
        frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(audio), 1/44100)
        abs_audio = [abs(ele) for ele in audio]
        sum_audio = sum(abs_audio)
        volume = 100
        #print(sum_audio)
    
        if sum_audio >= volume:
            bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.176849, 0.454112, 0.0435809), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False, snap=False, snap_elements={'INCREMENT'}, use_snap_project=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', use_snap_self=True, use_snap_edit=True, use_snap_nonedit=True, use_snap_selectable=False)
    
        elif sum_audio < volume:
            bpy.context.object.location[0] = 0
            bpy.context.object.location[1] = 0
            bpy.context.object.location[2] = 0
        
    elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
        bpy.context.object.location[0] = 0
        bpy.context.object.location[1] = 0
        bpy.context.object.location[2] = 0
        return {'CANCELLED'}
    
    elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    print("Let's go! :P")
    if 2 < 10:
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    else:
        self.report({'WARNING'}, "Ya wang-jangled it up, shmuck!")
        return {'CANCELLED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SpeakingPuppet.bl_idname, text=SpeakingPuppet.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SpeakingPuppet)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SpeakingPuppet) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   register() 

bpy.ops.object.speaking_puppet('INVOKE_DEFAULT')'''


I figured it out! Instead of having the event happen whenever I move the mouse, I instead put it at the bottom at the code as an 'else' function. So, if it doesn't sense the right mouse, left mouse, or the esc key, it will check if there is some input from the microphone. How come I couldn't think of this yesterday!?!
If anyone else tries this, do note that it might not look like anything is happening if your code does something in the viewport. I think another reason this was hard for me was, it only works after you hit the play button! Once that happened, I could see blender reading the mic, and it would move the cube when I spoke. So if your code isn't working, try pressing play? It helps blender take more samples per second, at least on my end with a microphone connected.
